# swift VAR restriction of types

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

how I can add restriction of types to **var** like this

```
var contentController: <UIViewController, MyProtocol> // wrong
var contentController: UIViewController where Self: MyProtocol // wrong
```

but it is wrong declarations for swift. For example what I want - true declarations for **func**

```
func setContentController<Controller:UIViewController>(_ controller: Controller) where Controller: MyProtocol
```

its fine work to **func**, but I do not add restriction for **var** or **typealias**